# Print japanese with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, unicode, character-encoding

I'm trying to print some Japanese to a page dynamically using jQuery, and it display nothing recognizable. I don't know what went wrong, I reduced the code to the most straight-forward, and it doesn't fix it. Or maybe it's just me being thick.

I use:

```
$('body').append('<p>日本語</p>');
```

Which should work, right?

And I get:

```
æ—¥æœ¬èªž
```

Huh?

Comment: Have you tried writing in static Japanese text first? Does this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you made sure that your page is set to use the Japanese character set? If not, make sure that your charset is defined in your `<head></head>` node :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=euc-jp">
```

Comment: @passcod ~ no prob. You should consider @Thilo's answer too, especially if you're going to be working with hoards of different character types. :)

Answer (score 0):

In some cases Utf-8 character set would be helpful. Add this in your Head node as below.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
```